# Is there a specific technical reason why the Brilliant Pebbles Missile Defense concept would not be effective today?

Tags: artificial-satellite

The Smart Rocks, later Brilliant Pebbles, concept for ballistic missile defense proposed thousands of orbiting self-guided rockets to detect and intercept ICBMs.

A 2001 paper from a Missile Defense Agency researcher: "Although the
program was cancelled due to opposition in Congress, and lack of interest
during the Clinton Administration, the aerospace technology developed
utilized a combination of essentially off-the-shelf commercial and military
technology that is still available to U.S. aerospace development."

From 1990: "The Defense Science Board (DSB) and the JASONs have recently reviewed the Brilliant Pebbles concept. The groups found the concept innovative and capable, with no fundamental flaws, and deserving of continued support."

Comment: 40 years is a long time. Things change…

Comment: Some not-entirely-plausible concerns have been raised about weaponization of Starlink.

Comment: It's an interesting question, however I don't think you could get a fact based answer.

Comment: Launch costs were never *the* problem, the US would probably have been willing to pay $55 billion if it would have worked. Cheaper launches would likely reduce the costs but wouldn't solve the problems of countermeasures and nuclear proliferation.

Comment: @GdD 'Countermeasures' sounds like an answer to my question, "why not?" Are there any sites that detail realistic countermeasures to such a widely distributed system?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because feasibility analysis of ballistic missile defense plans is not related to space exploration.

Comment: @Organic Marble ICBMs & DARPA's DRACO are military programs contributing directly to the technology of space exploration, as did the MOL and Brilliant Pebbles. Your statement is an opinion, it is transparently wrong, and is disingenuous. You seek to set yourself up as a 'gatekeeper' (the kind that lives under a bridge) to routinely attack new questions with your specious arguments.

Comment: From 1990: "The Defense Science Board (DSB) and the JASONs have recently reviewed the Brilliant Pebbles concept. The groups found the concept innovative and capable, with no fundamental flaws, and deserving of continued support." Do you need an explanation of who the JASONs are?

Comment: It takes 5 votes to close a question, so ranting at me will not help your case.

Comment: @DrBunny, whether ballistic missile defense is on topic or not is moot, your question wasn't a good fit for the site. For one thing it's very broad, the answer would need a book, for another there isn't sufficient factual information for an answer,requiring too much speculation and opinion. This is the judgement of the community, not one person. Personal attacks are not welcome.